When are recursive type aliases allowed in Typescript?
For example:
type Foo = string | Record<string, Foo>;
type Bar = string | Array<Bar>;
interface Foo2 {
  [key: string]: string | Foo2;
}

Why are Bar and Foo2 valid types, while Foo causes Type alias 'Foo' circularly references itself.? To me these cases look quite similar.
Playground Link

Recursion is allowed inside type arguments of interfaces since they're object types with statically known keys (Array<Bar> is fine as Array is an interface). Type arguments of type aliases generally cannot be recursive as they can be implemented in many ways, some of which are illegally circular. That's why Record<string, Foo> is rejected, as Record is a type alias. See ms/TS#41164. TS could be changed to allow this (e.g., ms/TS#57293) but it takes work. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a; if not, what's missing?

@jcalz Thank you. My confusion comes from that I didn't realize Record isn't an interface, unlike Array.

Record<K, V> can't be an interface because it's generic in K, the key type. Interfaces require statically-known keys (you can't write interface Record<K, V> { [k: K]: V }, it's invalid). So, shall I write an answer? The existing answer below is essentially correct, not sure it's worth either of our time. Let me know.

I've accepted the anser below. Thank you again for the explanation!

Outlined on the PR adding recursive types, the following are allowed:


Instantiations of generic class and interface types (for example Array).
Array types (for example Foo[]).
Tuple types (for example [string, Foo?]).


Foo uses a generic type alias (Record is defined using type rather than interface)
Bar uses a generic interface type
Foo2 uses a generic interface type
Defining a Record equivalent as an interface does work
interface RecordI<T> {
    [k: string]: T;
}

type Baz = string | RecordI<Baz>;

And so does its inlined equivalent
type Baz1 = string | {[key: string]: Baz1}

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33050#issuecomment-543365074
